# Reading values from app.config

Tags: c#, app-config

I have a connection string stored within a .config file which I don't know how to read from.
I've searched around and most I found is about how to read key/value pairs stored within AppSetting. But this file is organized differently. All I need is to get the value of ConnectionString.
**NOTE: I cannot modify `.config` file. It is given to me.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="Assessment.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <Assessment.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="ConnectionString" serializeAs="String"> //This value I need
                <value>Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=[%CURRENT%]\DB.mdb</value>
            </setting>
        </Assessment.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 6):

There will be Settings class in the namespace of your project (Assessment.Properties.Settings)

The class is autogenerated.

To access your connection string simply use

`Assessment.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString`

Comment: To test this I tried entering your code in Form_Load event but Apparently I don't have these classes. Is there something I should do for these to appear? All I've done is paste the .config file content into my application's App.config.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx) property to retrieve connection strings from the application configuration file.

You should be storing your connection strings in the [connectionStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.connectionstringssection.aspx) section of the configuration file.

Comment: Tried that already and it didn't work. This is not a configuration file I wrote myself. I'm asked to read the connection string from such .config file.

Comment: If you cannot change how the configuration file is organized, please add this to your question as it is relevant information.

Answer (score 2):

```
connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
```

and in your config

```
<appSettings> <add key="ConnectionString" value="whatever" /> </appSettings>
```

Comment: The `.config` file is given to me. I am not to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the custom configuration section handler I can only guess:

Try this in your code:

```
   var connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection
                    ("Assessment.Properties.Settings")["ConnectionString"];
```

But better still is switch to use Microsoft Built-in ConnectionString section
     `System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings`

Comment: `GetSection` returns an object and I apparently cannot use [] operator on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `userSettings' section like:

```
var userSection = (ConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("userSettings");
```

Comment: I'm getting null for some reason.